# How do I make my regular expression tab exclusion pattern not exclude ts?

Tags: regex

I am working with some tab delimited strings so I have been using the following matching pattern to match everything but the tabs:

```
[^\\t]+
```

Unfortunately, my pattern is exclude ts in the text.  For example:

```
"Jim\tand\tjane\twent\tto\twork."
```

matches the following:

```
Jim and jane wen o work.
```

Any ideas on how to exclude the tabs but include the ts.

Update:  I've tried using [^\t]+ on Rubular and RegexPal.  Neither site seems to recognize \t as a tab. Both however do recognize \t as a tab and a t.

Second Update:  I appears it was an interface issue. I put the pattern into the rails console and [^\t] did in fact work.  Thanks to everyone for your great comments and input.

Comment: Your regex matches everything except backslashes and `t`s

Comment: Why ts?  I thought I was simply escaping the tab.

Comment: because you escaped backslash. But I've got a feeling that you don't want to match anything except a *single* tab character (ASCII 0x09), but rather looking for a way to get rid of a *sequence* "backslash followed by character 't'". Am I right?

Comment: Have you tried using a string split function?

Comment: What I thought [^\t]+ did was to match everything but tabs.  Since I'm working with a tab delimited file, I would be very happy if I could achieve this result.

Comment: Honest Abe - I have tried using the split and it does work.  For my particular application however, a ragex solution would be perforable. I can always fall back to the split function.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor: I just checked, rubular **does** understand `[^\t]` as "anything but a tab character" in *regex*. But it treats `\t` inside your *test string* as a pair of characters: slash and t. And tab is not the same as slash + t. It'd be much easier if you provide us with a piece of your code which is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the user interface may be interfering with you a bit.  One half of the problem is that the `[^\t]` doesn't need the backslash to be escaped.

The other half of the problem is that the web interface doesn't accept tabs at the keyboard, so it thinks your test string is literally containing backslash followed by t.

Try typing a tab into an external text editor, and then copy and paste that tab into your test string in Rubular so it looks like whitespace.  Then the `[^\t]+` should match the non-tabs without omitting the 't' characters.

Answer (score 2):

Igor is correct. Updating your regular expression to `[^\t]+` should fix your issue.

Your original regexp `[^\\t]+` would be interpreted like this: match 1 or more,`+`, characters except,`^`, backslash, `\`, or a lowercase letter t, `t`.

Working Example on [rubular.com](http://rubular.com/r/MVMwkjeO2D) using `[^\x09]+` and "Jim and jane    went    to  work."

Working Example on [rubular.com](http://rubular.com/r/ajlxPFgED7) using `[^\t]+` and "Jim   and jane    went    to  work."

Comment: I'm using rubular to test my pattern and for whatever reason \t does not match a tab, but \\t does. Unfortunately, as Igor as pointed out, it also matches ts.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor: can you please explain what you mean by a tab? Is it a single character with ASCII code 9 **or** `\` + `t` as in your question? It does make difference.